# facebook sdk 3 Mobile App Install Ads in actionscript

Tags: facebook, mobile, actionscript, sdk, air

I'm making mobile application in Adobe AIR but can't find solution for integrating new facebook features.
There is a library supported by both Facebook and Adobe https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ but it lacks lots of new sdk parts.

Particularly I'm interested in having Mobile App Install Ads working. Hope I'm not alone with this and someone has similar issue. There are several variants in my mind: 
1. porting java sdk code to actionscript
2. creating ane extension

Any thoughts, suggestions, solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do this exact same thing. There's no way around it as far as I can see but to port the publishInstall code from a Mobile SDK. I like the Android SDK version for that.

The following code is from the Settings.java:

```
        GraphObject publishParams = GraphObject.Factory.create();
        publishParams.setProperty("event", "MOBILE_APP_INSTALL");
        publishParams.setProperty("attribution", attributionId);
        publishParams.setProperty("auto_publish", isAutoPublish);
        publishParams.setProperty("application_tracking_enabled", !AppEventsLogger.getLimitEventUsage(context));
        publishParams.setProperty("application_package_name", context.getPackageName());

        String publishUrl = String.format(PUBLISH_ACTIVITY_PATH, applicationId);
        Request publishRequest = Request.newPostRequest(null, publishUrl, publishParams, null);
```

It looks like a straight forward request to reproduce. I'll try to remember to update this after I get it done.